# Sending emails with Outlook.com using Indy

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-2007, indy10

In the past i could send emails successfully with Indy and Hotmail, but when i try to send using an Outlook account, i always get the 'Authentication unsuccessful' error. My username and password are correct, i can logon on Outlook.com webmail.

Here is my code :

```
idsmtp1.Host := 'smtp.outlook.com';
idsmtp1.port := 587;
idsmtp1.Username := 'myuser@outlook.com';
idsmtp1.Password := 'mypassword';
idsmtp1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
idsmtp1.usetls := utUseExplicitTLS;
idsmtp1.UseEhlo := true   ;

IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;

idsmtp1.connect;
idsmtp1.Send(idmessage1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've made zero changes to your code, and it decided to stop working, then there is an authentication issue with your Outlook.com account.

It's most likely that you need to enable 2-step verification and create an application password. Email services typically block you from using your standard password unless the app supports more modern login methods, and they force you to set up applications on your account to access it. You'll have to enable 2-step verification first before you can access the app passwords section.

[image]

These can be located at `Outlook.com > Options > Account Details > Security & Privacy > More Security Settings`

Comment: In 2-step verification, an app-specific password is only used for apps that don't support newer 2-step auth methods like OAuth. Those that do can utilize the actual account password.

Comment: I use to send using hotmail, not outlook ; maybe there is differences between the setup in both ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Right, but Indy doesn't support it though... does it? I haven't checked recently.

Comment: @delphirules AFAIK, they're the same thing. I believe that Hotmail users automatically use Outlook.com, but you're the one with the account here, you should already know this.

Comment: @JerryDodge I tried now with another hotmail account, and i get the same error message. No doubt the user and password are correct, i can login on both accounts in outlook.com

Comment: @delphirules Did you try what my answer suggests yet?

Comment: @JerryDodge Correcting, the hotmail account worked ! I'm looking for the page you suggested on my outlook account, get back to you soon

Comment: That's odd, i could make it work by changing the server from 'smtp.outlook.com' to 'smtp.live.com'

Comment: I can't understand, i could send 2 messages  and now get back to the 'Authentication unsuccessful' error again.

Comment: Outlook.com > Options > Account Details > Security & Privacy > More Security Settings >

Comment: I don't have this 'App passwords' on my screen and the 2-step verification is not enabled either. So far, i can't understand what is happening... i could send 2 messages, and now it does not work again.

Comment: Like I say in my answer, first enable 2-step verification, and then the app passwords. App passwords only works if 2-step verification is turned on, and thus they hide it if disabled.